# az synapse spark job submit

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

According to the documentation, using az synapse spark job submit, I can pass arguments using --arguments.  So far so good.
However, I cannot figure out to actually access those arguments in my code.  Here's my current effort:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("foo")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("foo").getOrCreate()
val start_time = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(LocalDateTime.now)
val appID = sc.getConf.getAppId


//let's get some arguments
val inputArgs = spark.sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.args").split("\\s+")
//val inputArgs = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.args").split("\\s+")
```

Either of those lines throw the following exception:

```
22/03/25 19:07:45 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.driver.args
java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.driver.args
```

So, how do I read the arguments in the Scala code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was overcomplicating this.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
...

val foo = args(0)
```